# MS Access pulls out five rows instead of four

Tags: c#, sql

I have made a top liked games list, this is my SQL code:

```
SELECT TOP 4 * FROM games ORDER BY games.likes DESC;
```

As you can see, the code itself selects FOUR games, but sometimes when games have the same amount of likes it displays five of them-..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdisb.png

Answer (score 6):

This is by design. Here is the relevant part [from the documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/all-distinct-distinctrow-top-predicates-HP001032205.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> ```
> SELECT TOP 25
> FirstName, LastName
> FROM Students
> WHERE GraduationYear = 1994
> ORDER BY GradePointAverage DESC;
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The TOP predicate does not choose between equal values. **In the preceding example, if the twenty-fifth and twenty-sixth highest grade point averages are the same, the query will return 26 records.**

You have the following options to fix this:

- add a second ORDER BY field that works as a tie-breaker or
- filter your list to four entries *again* in C#.

Comment: @itsme86: Indeed. :-) I was surprised to discover this, though. SQL Server only does this when you explicitly add a `WITH TIES` option.

Comment: I agree. I was surprised too.

Answer (score 3):

This is documented behavior.

From [Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/all-distinct-distinctrow-top-predicates-HA001231351.aspx):

```
SELECT TOP 25
FirstName, LastName
FROM Students
WHERE GraduationYear = 2003
ORDER BY GradePointAverage DESC;
```

> The TOP predicate does not choose between equal values. In the preceding example, if the twenty-fifth and twenty-sixth highest grade point averages are the same, the query will return 26 records.